# Failed to send email due to IIS pickup directory

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, smtpclient

We are working on project that send email using System.Net.Mail.SmtpException.

```
     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");

                    if (ConfigSetting.Is2008 || ConfigSetting.IsLocal)
                        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    else
                        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
 client.Send(message);
```

client.Send(message) throwing these two exceptions :

**1. If sending to local server then getting exception** :

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

**2. And on sending email using our configuration then facing this exception :**

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Cannot get IIS pickup directory.    at
>   System.Net.Mail.IisPickupDirectory.GetPickupDirectory()    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

I have done setting at IIS Manager in SMTP E-mail for : **Store e-mail in a pickup directory**

OR added manually :

```
client.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\EmailLocation";
```

But nothing resolved for error : **System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Cannot get IIS pickup directory.**

I am working on :

1. OS : Windows-8.1
2. IIS : Version-6

Answer (score 0):

Change to `System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory`